# xsltproc generates more output than expected

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to write a simple .xslt to process .xml files. But I've been confused - why text in tags `<tag>text</tag>` has also been printed?
Please look at the example:

> sample.xml

```
<source>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Joe</firstName>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
    </employee>
</source>
```

> style.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match="surname">
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why after calling: `xsltproc style.xslt sample.xml` I'm getting

```
Joe
<div>surname</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>surname</div>
```

only?

Comment: Given that "Joe" is in the firstName and not the surname element, is that actually the output you are getting? Could you clarify what exactly you're seeing with the input you've listed?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the next output:
<?xml version="1.0"?>


 Joe
 <div>surname</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Joe` is being [handled by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Text nodes are normally output by default. You need to override the default behavior.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

  <!--Added to match all other nodes/attributes.-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="surname">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Processing starts with the document node and there are [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) that keep processing going until your templates match. You already got one suggestion to override the default templates, another approach in your case could be to explicitly select only the surname elements for processing with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="source/employee/surname"/>
</xsl:template>
```